# Как получить имя активного пользователя из службы?

Tags: c#

Есть служба Windows, запускаемая от лица "LocalSystem", мне надо получить имя пользователя, который в данный момент работает, т.е. залогинен.   
При вызове `Environment.UserName` выводится "система" , т.е. не то, что надо мне.

**Дополнение**
Либо получить адрес папки /AppData, или /Documents, или любой другой, что лежит в папке пользователя.

Comment: Оно?

string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

Comment: А [что](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/22/712677.aspx) есть «активный пользователь»?

Comment: @NMD это вернет пользователя, который запустил службу. В моем случае "система".

@VladD пользователь, который работает в данный момент, в моем случае он всегда будет 1.

Comment: Угу. Но вы всё же не читали текст. А откуда система знает? У системы нет функции «дать того единственного пользователя, который гарантированно есть на машине @whispeer».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()` получить список процессов, запущенных на текущей машине, и с помощью `StartInfo.UserName` получить имена запустивших их пользователей.